# 15x15 gaussian mask in c

Tags: c, image-processing, mask, gaussian

I came across an 5x5 gaussian mask code in c, when I googling..
but I need 15x15 gaussian mask so I was just modified like this.

```
void createFilter(double gKernel[][15])
{
    // set standard deviation to 1.0
    double sigma = 7.0;
    double r, s = 2.0 * sigma * sigma;

    // sum is for normalization
    double sum = 0.0;

    // generate 5x5 kernel
    //for (int x = -2; x <= 2; x++)
    for (int x = -7; x <= 7; x++)
    {
        //for (int y = -2; y <= 2; y++)
        for (int y = -7; y <= 7; y++)
        {
            r = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
            gKernel[x + 7][y + 7] = (exp(-(r*r) / s)) / (M_PI * s);
            sum += gKernel[x + 7][y + 7];
        }
    }

    // normalize the Kernel
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; ++j)
            gKernel[i][j] /= sum;

}
```

but the output is different between the correct number of 15x15 gaussian mask.
What am I supposed to do to get the correct 15x15 mask coefficients?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you are considering as "correct"?

Comment: On a side note, calculating the square root only to square the result one line below seems unreasonable.

Comment: @hidefromkgb The calculation can be optimized heavily indeed. From precalculating the constants to utilizing the symmetry. Well, the whole thing is a constant, can be just hardcoded.

Comment: Probably sigma is too high, at 7.0.

Comment: Your formula doesn't seem to match the formula at Wikipedia [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) — the divisor is a constant √(2πσ²) but you seem to be using the square of that value (or are not using the square root of the expression in parentheses).  Without you showing what you expect vs what you get, it's hard to know how else to help you.